# SQL Server 2005 Calculations - Decimal Truncation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, decimal, truncation

I am updating a table within a case statement that is the following:

update MyTable
set FieldC =
(case

...

when FieldA = 'X' then FieldB * (600 / 10000) / 365

...

else null
end)
from MyTable

FieldB is assigned an integer and Field C is a float.

In the case when FieldA is X and FieldB is '7', the result I am getting is 0.  Nothing  else in the decimal when it should be 0.00115068...  If I change the formula to "...FieldB * .06 / 365" I get a different result - I get 0.00115 and the remainder of the decimal is missing.

Why would this be occurring?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses integer calculations if all expressions are integers. You can remedy this by e. g. using

```
FieldB * (600.0 / 10000) / 365
```